# Prepopulating survey in Surveymonkey with previous year's survey answers?

Tags: survey, surveymonkey

We're sending out the same survey to many of the same participants again this year. Since it is long, we would want to have all of their previous year's answers already filled in, so they would only need to mark any changes that happened throughout the year.

Is there a way to do this?

I've read about prepopulating answers using custom variables in the URL, but this seems to only be useful when prepopulating a small number of responses, not the entire survey.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious about this, as it is something that I was interested in doing as well, and reached out to SurveyMonkey. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem possible to pre-populate an already administered survey:

**Response from SurveyMonkey:**

*"I'm afraid it wouldn't be possible to pipe answers previously given on a survey into a new or same survey but taken months later.*

*You will be able to set up two different collectors on the same survey that you will be able to compare the results of for the same respondent (if you request them to identify themselves) but not pipe previously given or selected answers or with such a time gap in-between.*

*Since the responses given are based on cookies, it may be cookies are deleted and as such the same device (browser) would not remember ever taking that survey or what answers were given, it would leave a lot to chance and potentially disturb your result accuracies."*